# 301 redirect in ASP.NET MVC from known URL's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-301, global-asax

I have a .Net MVC 1 site that replaced a legacy. Google still has a stack of old URL's in its index and i need to 301 redirect them. All of the old URL's are .html or .php pages, i also have a db table for old urls and their new equivalent. I know what i need to do, im just unsure of how to do it! Here are my thoughts

1. somewhere in the global.asax catch the url requested using a regexp
2. do a db lookup to hopefully find the new url
3. if we found the new url then 301 redirect it. if not either 301 to the homepage or throw a 404

Ive tried hacking around myself with little luck, plus all of the examples i can find online dont really cover this example. Would really like to do this via code rather than adding about 80 seperate routes to the global.asax

Any help or links is greatly appreciated

Comment: I had the same problem with one of my sites. I did it by catching all .php and .html requests into one single RedirectController using 2 Routes. Within the redirect controller I matched the URL's by getting the old requested url from the database, and did a 301 redirect from there to the new one. But it might be different for you if your new URL's are still having .php and .html extensions

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [Handlers](http://dotnetperls.com/ashx). If the URLs are distinct enough, you could write a pretty broad entry in to urlMappings section of your web.config and then use the handler to re-route the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the catch all route and before returning that 404 I'd insert the logic to check if it needs a 301 instead.

```
[UrlRoute(Name = "404", Path = "{*path}", Order = 100)]
public ViewResult NotFound(string path) 
{

}
```